# Xamarin.Forms Previewer not exist

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-previewer

I couldn't find or start **Xamarin.Forms Previewer** using VS Community 2019 update 16.9.2.
As you can see from the attached screenshots after I've built the project I can't find away to toggle to XAML preview mode even the **View Designer** from context menu isn't working also **Shift + F7**. Also I can't fin **Xamarin.Forms Previewer** under **View** Menu >> **Other Windows**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4wnx.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqzCh.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW2xU.png

Answer (score 1):

> I couldn't find or start Xamarin.Forms Previewer using VS Community 2019 update 16.9.2.

As far as I know, there is no XAML Previewer in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9.2. For now, it use the Hot Reload insead and provide a live visual tree to receive a real-time view of your running XAML code. It shows a tree view of the UI elements of your running Xamarin.Forms application.

When you debug you project, by default, it appears on the IDE's left. If you don't see it, use **Debug > Windows > Live Visual Tree** to show it.

[image]

I have reported this problem for Microsoft team, maybe it will be restored in the next version, please wait a minute.

Comment: Cherry, thank you for reporting the problem to the Microsoft team. I really hope they bring back the XAML Previewer. While XAML Hot Reload and the XAML Visual Tree are nice features, the XAML Previewer is a *must have* when it comes to doing initial UI design. It allows fast and easy mockups of a UI. XAML Hot Reload comes into play later when you are debugging.