# xaml designer or previewer is not showing

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-previewer

Xamarin.Forms design view doesn't show for the preview of the .xaml What could I do? I looked for an answer and I did all the community recommendations but nothing works. I'm start thinking that Xamarin.Forms doesn't have a preview for .xaml I am right? or Where are those buttons? How could I get them?

[image]

This is my view:
[image]

Comment: So what is your vs version? And try "shift+F7"

Comment: @DavidZarzosoMoreno, there are many people encounter this problem, please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66694679/xamarin-forms-previewer-not-exist/66701483#66701483)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The XAML Previewer has been deprecated in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.8, and replaced by the XAML Hot Reload feature in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.9. Learn more about XAML Hot Reload in the documentation.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/?pivots=windows).

You may want to check [Xamarin.Forms 5.0+ Live Visual Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/live-visual-tree) also.

Comment: I really hope they un-deprecate XAML Previewer. The XAML Previewer is much better than XAML Hot Reload for designing user interfaces. XAML Hot Reload is better for debugging, but not for initial design work.

Comment: I agree initially I would start with xaml previewer the same for simple things, but at the same time I was hitting a lot of crash with previewer especially with custom controls, in several cases I had to use hot reload anyway because previewer is crashing with exceptions and not rendering anything.

Answer (score 2):

Open the sln file of the project instead of the project folder in Visual Studio solved the problem for my case.