# XAML designer doesn't work in my visual studio 2019

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

why XAML designer isn't available in my visual studio 2019 enterprise?
every thing in options is right and hot reload is active but I couldn't access to XAML designer.
in Xamarin android and WPF every thing is ok but in Xamarin forms not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/?pivots=windows)

> The XAML Previewer has been deprecated in Visual Studio 2019 version
> 16.8 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.8, and replaced by the XAML Hot Reload feature in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9 and Visual
> Studio for Mac version 8.9. Learn more about XAML Hot Reload in the
> documentation.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/66799028/